# Prometheus config working with only 1 version

Tags: prometheus

I have Prometheus working as a docker image. My source is :

```
 spec:
      containers:
      - name: prometheus
        image: quay.io/coreos/prometheus
```

The config that is working with this version of Prometheus is :

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 5s
scrape_configs:

- job_name: 'kubernetes_apiserver'
  tls_config:
    insecure_skip_verify: true
  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - api_servers:
    - http://172.29.219.102:8080
    role: apiserver

  relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_role]
    action: keep
    regex: (?:apiserver)


- job_name: 'docker_containers'
  metrics_path: '/metrics'
  tls_config:
    insecure_skip_verify: true
  static_configs:
     - targets:
       - 172.29.219.103:4194
       - 172.29.219.104:4194
       - 172.29.219.105:4194

- job_name: 'kubernetes_pods'
  tls_config:
    insecure_skip_verify: true
  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - api_servers:
    - http://172.29.219.102:8080
    role: pod
  relabel_configs:
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_name]
      action: replace
      target_label: pod_name
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_path]
      action: replace
      target_label: __metrics_path__
      regex: (.+)
```

Now I downloaded the latest version of Prometheus (v2.0.0) (standalone deployment on VM and NOT a docker image )and when I try to launch the same config in that version, I get the below ERROR.

```
caller=main.go:356 msg="Error loading config" err="couldn't load configuration (--config.file=/etc/prometheus-2.0.0.linux-amd64/prometheus.yml): Unknown... role \"apiserver\""
```

Does anyone know why one configuration is compatible with one version of Prometheus and not the other ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.x to 2.0 is a pretty big bump, and you should expect some backwards-incompatible changes.

You can find details about breaking/important changes in the [migration guide](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/2.0/migration/).

Details of the `kubernetes_sd_configs` are available for [2.0](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/2.0/configuration/configuration/#<kubernetes_sd_config>) and [1.8](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/1.8/configuration/configuration/#<kubernetes_sd_config>).

Also, please note the warning in the kubernetes_sd_configs section, it pretty much spells out that changes may occur even between minor versions.

> Kubernetes SD is in beta: breaking changes to configuration are still
>   likely in future releases.

Answer (score 0):

The removal of the `apiserver` role was back in 1.3.0, from the release email:

> the apiserver role was dropped as it was just a static configuration of the provided API server. Instead, the generically
>   available kubernetes service should be used in the endpoint discovery

There were no changes in kubernetes service discovery for 2.0.